# Deploy WCF service in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, wcf-hosting

I am newbie to WCF. I am looking to steps to deploy WCF on IIS and consume the service. 
I have follow the steps same as to deploy the Website on IIS, also set the default document to Service1.svc

Now when I am trying to consume this wcf service it is giving me the following error.

```
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://manish-pc:8000/Service1.svc?wsdl'.
The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
There was an error downloading 'http://manish-pc:8000/Service1.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8000/Service1.svc'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:8000/Service1.svc.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Follwing is my Service Details in Web.Config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="DemoWCF.Service1Behavior" name="DemoWCF.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/Service1.svc"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="DemoWCF.IService1"
                  bindingConfiguration="basicBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint> 
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicBinding" textEncoding="utf-8"></binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DemoWCF.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Please guide me where I'm lacking and what steps to make.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After search on google and watching videos. Finally I got the solution.

This error occur due to IIS configuration that I was not bother about.

1. open your IIS Manager console.
2. Make a separate applicaiton pool.
   a). Set .NET Framework version to 4.0
   b). Managed pipeline mode : Classic
3. Set Applicaiton Pool Identity to "LocalSystem".
4. Follow the steps same as to deploy a web application on IIS like creating a Virtual Directory.
5. Creatig the Virtual Directory set that Application Pool you have created.

And consume the WCF Service in Client application.

[Click here to watch the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIfx5qbx5MA)

Kindly Update this question / answer thread, if you find more about this.
Thanks :)

Comment: Letting a whole appilcation pool run as "LocalSystem" is quite a security risk.