# How to start wcf services in Dynamics crm 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm newbie to wcf services. how to start wcf services with dynamics crm. at what scenarious we have to go for wcf services.Any references plz

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamics CRM we have to write our own Web Services (`WCF/SOAP`) to provide limited set of `data/access` to the external users.

Here is an example:

We have 2 teams working in our office. 1 is `Java team` and the 2nd is us `CRM team.` To provide data of specific entities like: `Account, Contact, Case` we have written a `WCF Webservice` with the following functions:

`GetAccountByGuid`: Returns the Account against a specific GUID

`GetContactByGuid`: Returns the Contact against a specific GUID

`GetCaseByGuid`:  Returns the Case against a specific GUID

To create a new WCF Service in Visual Studio 2012: 
File->New->Project->WCF Service Application

To host/Start WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx

[Deploy WCF service in IIS 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724125/deploy-wcf-service-in-iis-7-5)